# Cómo agrupar filas dejando uno de los valores de una de las variables en Big Query SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Quería saber si hay alguna formula en al cual se agrupasen filas de una tabla conservando uno de los valores de la variable en la agrupación:

tabla1

```
  url              |   tags       |  páginas _vistas
www.helloworld.com |  bigquery,sql|  200
www.helloworld.com |  -           |  100
www.byeworld.com   |  python,java |  250
www.byeworld.com   |  -           |  150
```

y que el resultado fuese

```
  url              |   tags       |  páginas _vistas
www.helloworld.com |  bigquery,sql|  300
www.byeworld.com   |  python, java|  400
```

Por ahora solo he encontrado hacer un JOIN separando ambas tablas pero estoy seguro de que esto es más sencillo pero no soy capaz de verlo:

```
SELECT
url,
tags,
paginas_vistas

FROM 
(SELECT 
*
FROM tabla_1
WHERE tags != '-
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
*
FROM tabla_1
WHERE tags '-')
```

ON URL

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para ver el total de páginas vistas agrupadas por url, deberías utilizar GROUP BY, la cual agrupa filas que tienen los mismos valores y SUM para poder sumar el valor total de páginas _vistas:

```
SELECT url,SUM(paginas_vistas) 'Total páginas vistas'
FROM tabla_1
GROUP BY url
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que incluir la columna en una función de agregado.

```
SELECT
    url,
    MAX(tags) AS tags,
    SUM( paginas_vistas) AS paginas_vistas
FROM tabla_1
GROUP BY url;
```

Comment: Gracias! Pero me refería a una tabla que agrupe diferentes URLs y con diferentes valores. Edito la entrada....